# Modular Extension

Tags: modular

I came accross the term Modular Extension as a requirement of an application of I am developing. Any body know what a Modular Extension is all about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if something is *modular* it means it's independent to the rest of your application, so that you can switch it on or off as needed, or remove it entirely, without affecting other things.

If something is an *extension* it means it's not considered a core part of your application, but rather separate functionality that can be developed on its own. Usually, the ability to write extensions implies a relatively well thought-out design and a sophisticated API that allows outside clients to get at the relevant internals of your core application.

Otherwise, though, your question is a little too generic to give a precise answer without more information.